# Logic behind And and Or with numbers

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I know that 0 = false and 1 = true, but what if I have a condition like 2 And 5 in VBA?
I tried it and got the following results:

`2 And 5 = 0
34634 And 6346 = 74
2 Or 5 = 7
4 Or 5 = 5`

I can't seem to understand this, can someone please explain me?

Comment: `And` and `Or` perform [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: The `False` being `0` is correct. `True` is specified as `Not False`, with a numerical representation of `-1` - any non-zero integer value will convert to `True`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With vba one must do the entire Boolean expression each time

```
IF 2 = 0 and 5 = 0 Then
```

Comment: In VBA, in C#, in Java, in SQL, in... a *lot* of languages, actually. The difference with VBA is that `And` and `Or` "logical" operators are a lie: they're *always* bitwise operators (bitwise operations on Booleans happens to match the expectations of logical operators' behavior). In e.g. C# you have `&&` for logical-and, and `&` for bitwise-and, then `||` for logical-or, and `|` for bitwise-or. In VBA you use the same operators for bitwise and logical operations, is all.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer but an elaboration of Andrew Morton's comment. See Scott's for a solution.

[image]

Comment: It absolutely is an answer.